# delightful or delighted

Tags: word-choice, difference

"Each winter, residents and tourists alike are ________to see a snow festival taking place in Sapporo."

A.delightful

B.delighted

I think A is correct, but the answer key says B is right.Could you tell me why B is the correct one?

Comment: Have you looked up the two words in a dictionary? One means 'giving delight', the other 'feeling delight'.

Comment: It *is* potentially confusing, given that even though it wouldn't be common, it's possible to say the tourists were "full of delight" (more likely "filled with delight").

Comment: Both *delightful* and *delighted* are adjectives,  a friend can be **a delightful person** (fun, charming) or  **She is/was delighted to meet them**. Which means she was *very happy* to meet the people.

Comment: @PeterJennings An adjective could work in the blank, too. For example, "happy" or "eager".

Answer (score 1):

B is correct.  They are delighted--they experience joy.

If they were delight*ful*, they would cause others to experience joy--clearly not the meaning of the sentence.  The *snow festival* is delightful, not the people.

"Each winter, residents and tourists alike are delighted to see a [delightful] snow festival taking place in Sapporo."